# HTML input autocomplete not working with tag name title

Tags: html, input, autocomplete

HTML input autocomplete not working in Chrome when name="title"
I'm have no idea how make it work, but not rename name tag.
Maybe anyone know the trick to make it work?

```
<input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Название" autocomplete="on">
```

demo https://jsfiddle.net/Lhwampf3/1/